# How to remove a div without removing its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, removeclass

For example http://jsfiddle.net/skpfknxo/

It removes the div `#test` along with its children `#test2` and `#test3`.
I want to remove `#test` without removing its children.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#test2" ).unwrap();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skpfknxo/9/)

> The .unwrap() method removes the element's parent. This is effectively the inverse of the .wrap() method. The matched elements (and their siblings, if any) replace their parents within the DOM structure.

Comment: grad it helped happy coding mate

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skpfknxo/5/ here's a tiny problem..it will remove `#test` along with `#test4`..what if i only want to remove  `#test`?

Comment: Nice, didn't know this one.

Comment: rename the class inside `test4` into another name or create another selector.it will remove test4 because `test4` is parent of `test2` or you can have id for test2 which is the sibling of `test4` like this http://jsfiddle.net/skpfknxo/6/

Comment: glad it helped.if you need the updated version i updated the demo you can take a look. happy coding